# Android widget in different phones

Tags: android, android-widget

I created a widget. It shows the details of the WiFi, like network name, Ip and MAC address.
But i am not able to give a fixed size for the text which i am using in the widget. If the screen changes the text size also need to adjust with that. How we can do that ?

My xml file is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wifi_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
    android:paddingTop="22dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_on"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="12dp"
     />

</FrameLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_notconnected"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="7dp"
     />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_signal_strength"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_circle"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/circle_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/circle_hieght"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/onpress_wifi_icon_circle_null"
    android:src="@drawable/toggle" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_square"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/square_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/square_hieght"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:background="@drawable/onpress_network_info_squre_null"
    android:src="@drawable/togglenetwork" />

 </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you send your xml code where you use created the layout for widget

Comment: Add some code, and show what you've tried.

Comment: When you refer to fixed size, do you mean the the font size or the space available in the widget?

Comment: Have u tried making all as MatchParent instead of wrap content

Answer (score 1):

You should use `sp` for your `TextSize`:

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/wifi_status"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="12sp"
/>
```

[Read more.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)